# Can I move existing Windows 7 setup to a RAID-1 array?

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I have a the following setup:
machine with one 1TB hdd and with W7Ultimate installed on that drive (with RAID in BIOS).

Now I want to make it running as RAID 1, so I have two additional similar 1TB WD Reds.

Is there some easy way hot to do it? 
I tried HW switch to RAID 1, but it will format the drive, so I tried to clone existing OS into it, but it will lost that RAID settings.
I also tried to make RAID 1 in Intel Matrix storage in Windows, but it will says, that second drive is not big enough, etc and cannot be used for RAID.
Also I tried to convert both drives to dynamic type, but obviously Win won't boot from this type of units.

[image: screen from diskmgmt]

I'm slowly discovering, that it may not be possible.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of Disk Management with both drives connected? (You can launch that with `diskmgmt.msc`.)

Comment: @BenN sure I can, but it depends with which configuration you mean. I'm preparing these drives in my own computer via docking station (cloning from original 1TB Blue), so there are 2 additional 1TB RED drives.

Comment: OK I added diskmgmt screen with some description.